# Google URLfetch Quota reached each morning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I am not much of a coder but I have a single spreadsheet in my google docs that interacts with a website's API to pull quantitative data and display it in a helpful way. My problem is I keep reaching my urlfetch quota from google without ever accessing the spreadsheet. As in, the limit is reached upon waking up in the morning, at some point throughout the day the quota resets and I might load the spreadsheet once or twice, then by next morning the quota is reached again.

I can't imagine I am personally reaching the 20k limit. The spreadsheet is literally a dozen cells with numbers, nothing fancy here. My best guess is the problem has something to do with the fact I copied this spreadsheet from another user (who shared it with many, many others). But I was under the impression that the quota was gmail-account specific, so that should not matter?

Comment: Please add example of your code. Also make sure there's no other scripts which use UrlFetchApp in your Google account.

Comment: We can't help you until you share some code.